# chartkick.js tooltip currency format

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, chartkick

I am using chartkick.js with Google Charts. My question is about how I can change the format if value inside the tooltip, for a currency format, for example.

Current:

[image]

In Highchrats we can use:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false,
    },
    lang: {
      decimalPoint: ',',
      thousandsSep: '.'
    }
  });
```

Then

```
 tooltip: {
    pointFormat: "Value: {point.y:.2f} mm"
 }
```

My code for image below:

```
   data = [
   {"name":"2015", "data": gon.serie1},
   {"name":"2014", "data": gon.serie2}];

   new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-1", data, {
     "library":
     {
       "backgroundColor" : "white"
     },
     "discrete": true
   });
```

How I can achieve the same using googlechart adapter for chartkick.js

Some data:

`[["Jan", "69.880,65", "Hello"], ["Fev", "45.613,46", "Hello"], ["Mar", "60.895,95", "Hello"], ["Abr", "46.559,75", "Hello"], ["Mai", "45.598,76", "Hello"], ["Jun", "54.398,26", "Hello"], ["Jul", "27.309,40", "Hello"], ["Ago", "48.609,09", "Hello"], ["Set", "71.448,70", "Hello"], ["Out", "103.479,39", "Hello"], ["Nov", "103.451,56", "Hello"], ["Dez", "71.913,10", "Hello"]]`

Comment: @WhiteHat The problem is that the tooltip. I add a new image to the question

Comment: @WhiteHat I formatted the data before moving to the chartkick. For example, the number as 100,540.40. But in the tooltip shows only 100,540, for example

Comment: can you share a sample of the data -- does it look anything like this column value --> `{v: 102040.2, f: "102,040.20"}` -- only other way I know would be to [add another column for the tooltip](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-tooltip-content)...

Comment: @WhiteHat I added some data to the question. You can notice that I already try to use another column for the tooltip. But it seems to be ignored

Comment: when adding column for tooltips, it has to be defined as such --> `role: 'tooltip'`